# Program crashes when application becomes active from background and UItableView is reloaded

Tags: ios

Hi Guys I am creating a iOS(Universal) application.
My problem is that in my application there is a UITableView that works fine if the application doesn't goes to background(By pressing home button or by clicking a URL link).

If the application goes into the background, when it gets active, reloading a cell or the whole table view crashes the whole application.

Any Solution???

Is removing the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will make some difference??

The code is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    Animation *animation = [animationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = animation.title;

    if(animation.isAnimationEnabled){
        cell.imageView.image = OnImage;
    }else {
        cell.imageView.image = OffImage;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more info? What kind of crash, some code, wich sentence is crashing?

Comment: It's hard, actually it's impossible to say anything without seeing the code. What do you do on entering background/foreground. How do your `tableViewDataSource` methods look like? `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is there for a reason (reusing cells) but it has to be used correctly.

Comment: Check whether you deallocate anything important in viewDidUnload.

Comment: after enabling NSZombieEnabled, in console after the crash I get this:   *** -[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5cd3b90

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure all the view controllers in your app can survive arbitrary number of cycles of view load/view unload. Check whether you remove something in viewDidUnload that is used in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Well, I haven't removed any thing in viewDidUnload. My main problem is with UITableView, other things are working good.

Comment: I got it finally.

The problem was due a the autoreleased object of the Image. Well I don't know why autoreleased objects are deallocating while in use in my application.

Comment: Probably because the UIImageView containing it is deallocated? You should store the UIImage as strong property of some class.